# Looking for hands on Inbound and outbound SOAP example in salesforce

Tags: soap-api, webservices, soap, inboundservices

Looking for hands on Inbound and outbound SOAP example in salesforce.I have some basic knowledge about SOAP using Java.But just want to have some examples from salesforce for Inbound & outbound SOAP example.Any link or Docs would help me a lot.I am not sure if it is the right forum to ask for.But i feel people can help me learning inbound & outbound SOAP webservices example in salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some SOAP API Sample WSDL Structures:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/salesforce-soap-api-sample-wsdls.html

And some older Sample SOAP Messages:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Sample_SOAP_Messages

The API has changed in the meantime so use these for learning purposes only